# How can a composite text field in Solr support language rules?

Tags: solr

My original composite text field was setup in schema.xml , like this:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*_t" dest="text" maxChars="3000"/>
```

where "_t" fields are defined as:

```
<dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_general"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

and the "text_general" type is defined as:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Then, when I include "text" in the *qf* in the query using edismax, the *q* string is searched for in all the fields with the suffix "_t".

**The problem is that searches across all text fields do not use language-specific rules.**  For example, if I set the *q* string to "endmills", and the value of a text field is "endmill", the record does not show up in the query results.

To rectify this, I tried making the composite field a language specific type.

```
<field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

where "text_en" is defined with English-language rules

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
            />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Still, querying for "endmills" does not find a record that has a text field with the value "endmill".

However, when "fieldx_ten" is of value "endmill", and the "_ten" suffix is defined as

```
<dynamicField name="*_ten"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true" />
```

If I include "fieldx_ten" in the *qf* string, the record is found when I search for "endmills".

How do I a full-text search with all text fields that will use language-specific rules, such as singular/plural?

Answer (score 0):

copyField instructions are applied *before* any processing takes place, so its the type of the destination field that determines how your content will be processed.

The solution is to have distinct fields and field types for all your supported languages, and then include those field names in your `qf` parameter - that way Solr will search all the fields, and apply different rules for each field depending on the language of that field.

If you want to have more robust handling (i.e. only index the content into the field matching your definition, and not into all fields regardless of language), you can use the [langid](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/detecting-languages-during-indexing.html) feature of Solr.